# fault tolerance in MPICH/OpenMPI

Tags: mpi, openmpi, fault-tolerance, mpich

I have two questions-

**Q1**. Is there a more efficient way to handle the error situation in MPI, other than check-point/rollback? I see that if a node "dies", the program halts abruptly.. Is there any way to go ahead with the execution after a node dies ?? (no issues if it is at the cost of accuracy)

**Q2**. I read in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144309/what-is-the-best-mpi-implementation", that OpenMPI has better fault tolerance and recently MPICH-2 has also come up with similar features.. does anybody know what they are and how to use them? is it a "mode"? can they help in the situation stated in **Q1** ?

kindly reply. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MPI - all implementations - have had the ability to continue after an error for a while.  The default is to die - that is, the default error handler is MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL - but that can be set (eg, see the discussion [here](http://beige.ucs.indiana.edu/I590/node85.html)).  But the standard doesn't currently much beyond that; that is, it's hard to recover and continue after such an error.   If your program is sufficiently simple - some sort of master-worker type of setup - it may be possible to continue this way.

The [MPI forum](http://www.mpi-forum.org/) is currently working on what will become MPI-3, and error handling and fault tolerance will be an important component of the new standard  (there's a [working group](https://svn.mpi-forum.org/trac/mpi-forum-web/wiki/FaultToleranceWikiPage) dedicated to the topic).  Until that work is complete, however, the only way to get stronger fault tolerance out of MPI is to use earlier, nonstandard, extensions.   [FT-MPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/ftmpi/) was a project that developed a very robust MPI, but unfortuantely it's based on MPI1.2; a very early version of the standard.  The claim [here](http://vgrads.rice.edu/research/programming_tools/ft-mpi/) is that they're now working with OpenMPI, but I don't know what's become of that.   There's [MPICH-V](http://mpich-v.lri.fr/), based on MPI2, but that's more checkpoint-restart based than what I think you're looking for.

**Updated to add**: The fault tolerance didn't make it into MPI-3, but the working group continues its work and the expectation is that something will result from that before too long.