# Dynamic nodes in OpenMPI

Tags: mpi, distributed-computing, openmpi

In MPI, is it possible to add new nodes after it is started? For example, I have 2 computers already running a parallel MPI application. I start another instance of this application on a third computer and add it to the existing communicator. All computers are in a local network.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not currently possible to add new nodes to a running MPI application. MPI is designed to know the total number of nodes when the program starts.

Work is being done (on [MPI-3](http://meetings.mpi-forum.org/MPI_3.0_main_page.php), for example) on handling nodes that go down. Maybe if you can add faulty nodes back, then you can add new ones, but that's the closest thing I can think of. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386630/fault-tolerance-in-mpich-openmpi/5390915#5390915) for more info on approaches to MPI fault tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for a MPI2 program to spawn new ranks. The function is [MPI_Comm_spawn](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.4/man3/MPI_Comm_spawn.3.php) and it starts up children on a new MPI communicator. That is to say the new ranks have a different MPI_COMM_WORLD from the previously running ranks. It should be possible to make a new communicator that contains all of the current running ranks though.

Comment: I think this is true for already-connected nodes, but not for external, new-to-comm-world nodes.